# Packages conflict in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

while using flutter_datetime_picker package, i get an error.

Notice:
I used as in the import but it didn't work.

`import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart'as datetime;`

Here is the error

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_datetime_picker-1.5.1/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:6:1: Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' and 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'.
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_datetime_picker-1.5.1/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:199:31: Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' and 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'.
        this.theme = theme ?? DatePickerTheme(),
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I used 'as' in the import but it didn't work.

I tried
flutter clean,
flutter pub get,
flutter run,
but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Change your import line using `as` like this:

```
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart' as dpt
```

And if somewhere you need to use `datetime_picker_theme`, call `dpt.DatePickerTheme()`

Comment: Yes , I did that before and I tried it again according to your comment, but still i get the same error.